# Функция, которая принимает на вход функцию-обработчик и дерево, а возвращает отображенное дерево

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать  функцию, которая принимает на вход функцию-обработчик и дерево, а возвращает отображенное дерево.

Вот дерево:

```
const tree = {
  name: '/',
  type: 'directory',
  meta: {},
  children: [
    {
      name: 'ETC',
      type: 'directory',
      meta: {},
      children: [
        {
          name: 'NGINX',
          type: 'directory',
          meta: {},
          children: [],
        },
        {
          name: 'CONSUL',
          type: 'directory',
          meta: {},
          children: [{ name: 'CONFIG.JSON', type: 'file', meta: {} }],
        },
      ],
    },
    { name: 'HOSTS', type: 'file', meta: {} },
  ],
};
```

Мое решение(которое очевидно, не верное)

```
const map = (f, tree) => {

  const newEl = f(tree);
  const childrens = newEl.children
if(newEl.type === 'directory'){
   return [newEl, childrens.map(el => map(f,el))]
}
 return {newEl};
};
```

Вот вызов:

```
 map(n => ({ ...n, name: n.name.toLowerCase() }), tree);
```

Comment: а что получить-то надо? Какой результат должен быть для приведенного примера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть подправил. Вы получаете результат `map`, но не присваиваете его элементам `children`. Так же не надо возвращать массив, так как Вы хотите вернуть обратно дерево. После выполнения `map` прототипа `Array`, значения передадутся по ссылке, поэтому просто присвойте `children` новые к старому массиву. Последний `return` не нужно превращать в объект, так как Вы и так имеете объект на входе.

```js
const tree = {
  name: '/',
  type: 'directory',
  meta: {},
  children: [
    {
      name: 'ETC',
      type: 'directory',
      meta: {},
      children: [
        {
          name: 'NGINX',
          type: 'directory',
          meta: {},
          children: [],
        },
        {
          name: 'CONSUL',
          type: 'directory',
          meta: {},
          children: [{ name: 'CONFIG.JSON', type: 'file', meta: {} }],
        },
      ],
    },
    { name: 'HOSTS', type: 'file', meta: {} },
  ],
};

const map = (f, tree) => {

  const newEl = f(tree);
  if(newEl.type === 'directory') newEl.children = newEl.children.map(el => el = map(f,el));
  return newEl;
};

const result = map(n => {n.name = n.name.toLowerCase(); return n;}, tree);
console.log(result)
```